# Instagram API - inconsistent use cases and associated scopes?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I recently entertained the idea of developing an app that aggregates Instagram data of a small community and displays it in different UI clusters, derived by certain analytics. While the API provides all the required endpoints for my requirements, I started re-inventing the app over and over again, to satisfy the Instagram platform policy, terms and conditions as well as the login permissions for the different scopes.

According to [Instagram API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) there are 3 categories for the scopes of all apps:

1. To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps: **basic**

   > *This use case is meant for apps that allow the general public to login with Instagram to get their own content; for example, an app that allows people to print their own pictures. Apps that fall into this use case will only have access to the basic permission.*
2. To help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and digital media rights: **basic**, **public_content**, **comments**, **relationships**, **likes**, **follower_list**

   > *This use case is meant for products that don't have a public facing login integration, but are gated to brands and advertisers. The product must support either multiple brands and advertisers (e.g. a social media management platform) or multiple users within a single brand or advertiser organisation.*
3. To help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution: **basic**, **public_content**, **comments**

   > *This use case is meant for products that don't have a public facing login integration, but are gated to broadcasters and publishers. The product must support either multiple broadcasters and publishers, or multiple users within a single broadcasters or publisher organization.*

Ideally, my app would benefit as many analytical endpoints as possible, particularly if I can process the list of followers and public content. This means my app should fall under group (2). However, the target community of this app was not consisted of brands and advertisers. Group (3) is also not an option, since my community is consisted of individuals. Then I was thinking that group (1) will fit my needs. But that was also not the case, since according to [platform policy](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), I won't be allowed to put the media in different UI clusters:

> *You cannot replicate the core user experience of the Instagram apps or web site. For example, do not build a media viewer.*

Then I started comparing the use cases with existing live apps. I noticed that if they would carefully follow the terms and conditions, as well as platform policies, they would also be unfit for all rules imposed by Instagram. Let me provide examples:

- **[minter.io](https://minter.io/)** (*broadcasters == individuals?*)

  minter.io focuses on Instagram analytics. Thus, it falls in group (2). However, anyone can register on this system, meaning any individual that owns an Instagram account. How is this a valid case when *brands and advertisers are not gated*? Furthermore, even if those are somehow filtered in some future phase (which they claim they do manually), why is it allowed to generate a report of a "competitor" account, when the ID of that account could be any individual, and not an advertiser?
- **[pikore.com](http://www.pikore.com)** (*discover / search function?*)

  Apart from having the similar issues of minter.io, where everyone can login, I fail to understand how is it possible for pikore.com to provide a "discover" functionality which is exactly what Instagram offers on its mobile apps? Is that not breach of platform policy? Or the fact that it is also able to display all media items of a given account mixed with advertisement? For example: [pikore.com/arianagrande](http://www.pikore.com/arianagrande). This breaches also other terms stated in [General Terms](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) of Platform Policy:

  > *24. Add something unique to the community. Don't use the Instagram APIs to replicate or attempt to replace the functionality or essential user experiences of Instagram.com or any of Instagram's apps.*
  >
  > *25. Respect the way Instagram looks and functions. Don't offer experiences that change it.*
  >
  > *26. Don't attempt to build an ad network on Instagram.*
- **[ElseWatcher](http://www.elsewatcher.com/)** (*another media viewer?*)

  I absolutely adore this app. But the fact that the Instagram data is organized by location and date, it seems to me that it's another media viewer with extra functionalities.
- **[socialbakers.com](http://www.elsewatcher.com/)** (*free social tracker?*)

  socialbakers.com, while providing an amazing interface, it requests **public_content** scope for any individual user of instagram.com. On top of that, without providing any mechanism to gate the broadcasters, offers their services as "Free Instagram Analytics Tool".

Maybe I am wrong, but the way I see it, the Instagram API rules, are not applied consistently to all 3rd party apps. Can anyone explain whether those are inconsistencies indeed, or whether I got things the wrong way?

While at it, I would also like to know how is it possible to have the term clause *"1. Instagram users own their media* (stated [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/)) in conjunction with *"17. Don't apply computer vision technology to User Content, without our prior permission"* (stated [here](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)). Does that mean that if I am an Instagram API user that agrees to these terms, and I perform computer vision on any image that also happens to be on Instagram, that I am breaching terms?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this cases?

simplymeasured.com/freebies/instagram-analytics

pro.iconosquare.com/pricing

websta.me

unionmetrics.com/free-tools/instagram-account-checkup/

After June 1st all Instagram 3rd party apps should pass a review. The review should contain video screencast with

> Provide a link to a video screencast showing the experience in your
>   app. Please show how your integration uses all permissions you are
>   requesting, any interface to moderate content or getting rights to
>   media, and any Instagram login experience. Since your app may be in
>   sandbox mode, you can use data from sandbox users to showcase the
>   integration.

I think, Instagram wouldn't have approved any app which violate their rules.

Comment: Martin, I believe your comment is just a comment, and not an answer. 

simplymeasured is a good example, since they review the account upon sign up. Union Metrics is not relevant, since they do not request public_content scope. 

For iconosquare, although the access is available to anyone with Instagram account, at least the authorized users are defined in their terms and conditions. And websta offers their analytics to any individual.

I've seen some screencasts, which were before June 1st. And I still don't understand why those have been approved.

Comment: simplymeasured - check out my link, their free report available to anyone and they ask for the public_content scope